# Prevent if() shortcutting in async code

Tags: c#

I have a set of methods that return a `Task<boolean>`, which have to run sequentially.  I want to know if any of the tasks return true.  All of the tasks have to be run, regardless of the result of the previous tasks.

I can't use a)

```
var success =  (await TaskMethod1() || await TaskMethod2() //etc);
```

Because TaskMethod2() may not execute because of If optimization; or b)

```
var success = await Task.WhenAll(new[] { TaskMethod(), TaskMethod2() //etc});
```

Because they have to be run sequentially.

This has led to the following awkward and verbose code

```
var success = await TaskMethod1();
if (await TaskMethod2()) 
  success = true; // Repeated for all tasks
```

Does anybody know of a more elegant way, perhaps using ContinueWith?

Comment: Why not use ContinueWith() to jsut properly chain them? That is one of the thigns you got a task for, after all (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991174.aspx)

Comment: @Christopher And what is `await` for? Its precisely the sequencing operation of asynchronous tasks.

Comment: @Christopher is the result of chained tasks results using ContinueWith available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
var success =  (await TaskMethod1() | 
                await TaskMethod2() |
                /*etc.*/ );
```

`||` is the short-circuited *or*, and `|` is the non short-circuited version. Both left and right operands will be evaluated no matter what their result is.

If you need all tasks to run no matter what the result is, then use `|`.

Comment: Why indeed - I wasn't even aware of |.  Thanks @InBetween

Comment: @AlanClark: People often think that `|` only works on integers and only does bitwise logic, but in fact it works just fine on bools. I note that you could also write your program as `bool success = false; success |= await M1(); success |= await M2(); ...`